# Why does str(KeyError) add extra quotes?

Tags: python, exception, keyerror

Why does the string representation of `KeyError` add extra quotes to the error message?  All other built-in exceptions just return the error message string directly.

For example, the following code:

```
print str(LookupError("foo"))
print str(KeyError("foo"))
```

Produces the following output:

```
foo
'foo'
```

I have tried this with a sampling of other built-in exceptions (`IndexError`, `RuntimeError`, `Exception`, etc) and they all return the exception message without the quotes.

`help(KeyError)` says that `__str__(...)` is defined in `KeyError`, as opposed to the `LookupError`, which uses the one defined in the `BaseException` base class.  This explains how the behavior is different, but doesn't explain **why** `__str__(...)` is overridden in `KeyError`.  The Python docs on [built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) don't shed any light on this discrepancy.

Tested against Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is done so that you can detect `KeyError('')` properly. From the [`KeyError_str` function source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bffa0b8a16e8/Objects/exceptions.c#l1270):

```c
/* If args is a tuple of exactly one item, apply repr to args[0].
   This is done so that e.g. the exception raised by {}[''] prints
     KeyError: ''
   rather than the confusing
     KeyError
   alone.  The downside is that if KeyError is raised with an explanatory
   string, that string will be displayed in quotes.  Too bad.
   If args is anything else, use the default BaseException__str__().
*/
```

And indeed, the [`traceback` printing code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bffa0b8a16e8/Lib/traceback.py#l205) will not print the exception value if `str(value)` is an empty string.